# React Hook error : Invalid hook call: mismatching versions of React and the renderer or breaking the Rules of Hooks or more than one copy of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm fairly new to react and using hooks. I'm using downshift plugin and want to show a MultiSelection dropdown. I'm using hooks to do that but I keep getting this error in the browser:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as
> React DOM) You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks You might have
> more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to
> debug and fix this problem.

I have read the doc and checked for any rules broken but as per my knowledge everything is correct.
Here is my function that uses hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useCombobox, useMultipleSelection } from 'downshift'

const DropdownMultipleCombobox=()=> {
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
const {
    getSelectedItemProps,
    getDropdownProps,
    addSelectedItem,
    removeSelectedItem,
    selectedItems,
} = useMultipleSelection({ initialSelectedItems: [Demoitems[0], Demoitems[1]] })
const getFilteredItems = (Demoitems) =>
    Demoitems.filter(
        (item) =>
            selectedItems.indexOf(item) < 0 &&
            item.toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue.toLowerCase()),
    )
const {
    isOpen,
    getToggleButtonProps,
    getLabelProps,
    getMenuProps,
    getInputProps,
    getComboboxProps,
    highlightedIndex,
    getItemProps,
    selectItem,
} = useCombobox({
    inputValue,
    Demoitems: getFilteredItems(Demoitems),
    onStateChange: ({ inputValue, type, selectedItem }) => {
        switch (type) {
            case useCombobox.stateChangeTypes.InputChange:
                setInputValue(inputValue)
                break
            case useCombobox.stateChangeTypes.InputKeyDownEnter:
            case useCombobox.stateChangeTypes.ItemClick:
            case useCombobox.stateChangeTypes.InputBlur:
                if (selectedItem) {
                    setInputValue('')
                    addSelectedItem(selectedItem)
                    selectItem(null)
                }

                break
            default:
                break
        }
    },
})
return (
    <div>
        <label {...getLabelProps()}>Choose some elements:</label>
        <div style={comboboxWrapperStyles}>
            {selectedItems.map((selectedItem, index) => (
                <span
                    style={selectedItemStyles}
                    key={`selected-item-${index}`}
                    {...getSelectedItemProps({ selectedItem, index })}
                >
                    {selectedItem}
                    <span
                        style={selectedItemIconStyles}
                        onClick={() => removeSelectedItem(selectedItem)}
                    >
                        &#10005;
                    </span>
                </span>
            ))}
            <div style={comboboxStyles} {...getComboboxProps()}>
                <input
                    {...getInputProps(getDropdownProps({ preventKeyAction: isOpen }))}
                />
                <button {...getToggleButtonProps()} aria-label={'toggle menu'}>
                    &#8595;
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul {...getMenuProps()} style={menuMultipleStyles}>
            {isOpen &&
                getFilteredItems(Demoitems).map((item, index) => (
                    <li
                        style={
                            highlightedIndex === index ? { backgroundColor: '#bde4ff' } : {}
                        }
                        key={`${item}${index}`}
                        {...getItemProps({ item, index })}
                    >
                        {item}
                    </li>
                ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
}

export default DropdownMultipleCombobox;
```

my React component where I call the function :

```
export class TypeItemCollection extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (<DropdownMultipleCombobox/>)
}
}
```

my package.json:

```
{
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
"babel-types": "^6.26.0",
"browserify": "^17.0.0",
"downshift": "^6.1.7",
"emotion": "^9.2.12",
"emotion-server": "^9.2.12",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"moment-datetime": "0.0.2",
"react": "^16.8.2",
"react-datepicker": "^4.6.0",
"react-datetime": "^3.1.1",
"react-dom": "^16.8.2",
"react-emotion": "^9.2.12",
"react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
"react-jss": "^8.6.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
"react-select": "^3.2.0",
"reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
"styled-components": "^4.0.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.7",
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.16.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
"babel-jest": "^27.4.5",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babelify": "^10.0.0",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
"jest": "^27.4.5",
"react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
"typescript": "^4.5.4",
"webpack": "^5.65.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
}
}
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Where does `Demoitems` come from ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found out that I had an extra copy of React running, after removing it hooks worked!!

Comment: how did you find about the second react instance?

Comment: How did you remove extra copy of reeact

Comment: what a evil person. anyways, Did you remove from the package file?